# Cakephp, adding a view to a sidebar

Tags: php, html, cakephp, view, sidebar

I'm struggling trying to understand cakephp's views, blocks and layouts.

I need everypage to show a left and right sidebar which content might change. At this moment I have the right sidebar defined in /pages/home.ctp but I'm guessing it would be better to extend that sidebar since it has to appear in everypage. Correct me if that thought is wrong.

Then, I have this view *add.ctp* for the '*usuarios*' table, it practically shows the fields login and password. I want to show this view in the sidebar, but I'm really lost as how to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Lets make this thing easy. Like @patrick said, there is a lots of way.

Start with layout file. Rearrange your default.ctp layout like-

**default.ctp layout**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <?php echo $this->element('header');?>
    </div>

    <div id="left-sidebar">
      <?php echo $this->element('left-sidebar');?>          
    </div>

    <div id="content">    
        <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>    
        <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
    </div>

    <div id="right-sidebar">
        <?php echo $this->element('right-sidebar');?>           
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
           <?php echo $this->element('footer');?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now create elements ctp files as header.ctp, left-sidebar.ctp, right-sidebar.ctp and so on and place them to `app/View/Elements`.

Your left-sidebar.ctp file may looks like this...

**left-sidebar.ctp**

```
    // to show login form //
if you just need to show on view.ctp place few logic here for login form.
//end login form//

show other sidebar contents
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do it, depending on your Cake version. If you're using >=2.1 (which  I assume you are since you asked about blocks), then you should try those to see if they work for your setup. The way I usually do things is that if all views for a controller need common markup then those view files would extend a base view within the Controller directory, e.g.

```
#/View/Posts/index.ctp
<?php
    $this->extend('_skel'); //arbitrary filename, I use '_skel' since that makes sense
    echo $this->Html->para(null, 'Hello');

#/View/Posts/_skel.ctp
<?php
    echo $this->Html->div('sidebar', 'Sidebar for posts...');
    echo $this->fetch('content'); // This gets all output from the Posts/index.ctp view
```

Then all your Posts views which extend _skel will have the sidebar automatically.

Your login module might make sense as an element - something that could be used anywhere in your views.